# Inserting 0 (zero) becomes null in Database

Tags: sql, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012

I'm using Entity Framework to insert some data into my database (sql server 2012).
After inserting a 0 value to a float field, it appears as null in the database.

```
        using (var db = new myDB()) {
            Part_Properties pp = new Part_Properties {
                part_id = 7007,
                properties_id = 31,
                value_num = 0
            };
            db.Part_Properties.AddObject(pp);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

according to the profiler, this is being sent:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Part_Properties]([part_id], [properties_id], [value_num], [value_char], [info])
values (@0, @1, @2, null, null)
',N'@0 int,@1 int,@2 float',@0=7007,@1=31,@2=0
```

and the result in the DB is this:
part_id = 7007, properties_id = 31, value_num = null

but i need this value to be 0.

any ideas?

Comment: If you insert data using SQL query, does this also happens?

Comment: This seems strange. Maybe you have some kind of trigger on the table?

Comment: Thx for the Hint @DanielHilgarth!
i had a trigger which sets my fields to null if there is an empty string. value_char = NULLIF(value_char, ''), value_num = NULLIF(value_num, ''), ....
Seems that NULLIF(..,'') triggers when there comes a 0. But ofcourse i dont need that for my value_num field.

Comment: `CAST('' AS INT)` returns `0` which is why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but accordingly this should not happen. You can rather go vice versa on this by defining null and converting it to '0'.

Please check if there are some rule over riding your statement.